# How should I set up SELinux to allow my apache to remotely access postgresql?

Tags: linux, apache, selinux

This is my database [RiceLncPedia](http://3dgenome.hzau.edu.cn/RiceLncPedia/). When I do not change SElinux (enabled by default), some pages that require remote posgresql will appear Permission denied (such as [this](http://3dgenome.hzau.edu.cn/RiceLncPedia/Transcripts.html)). When I turn off SElinux using `sudo setenforce 0`, these pages can all be Normal visit.

But for the sake of security, I want to meet the normal access of the database without closing SElinux. Do I need to change anything?

my system:

```
[yxu@localhost js]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow apache to access to your DB:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```